# Crystal Reports pass parameter to sub report using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports, send, subreport

I have been trying to pass parameter to crystal report subreport using Vb.Net but failed in every time.

I could successfully pass parameter to main report but not sub report.

Main report contains master information about an employee and the sub report has detailed info about his academic qualifications. All linked using serviceNo of type int. I have parameter in both reports called serviceNo.

Here is my code:

```
Dim frmReport As New frmReport
Dim repDoc As New ReportDocument

Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = serviceNo
crParameterFieldDefinitions = repDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("serviceNo")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
```

After this peace of code I get a prompt requesting the serviceNo parameter of the sub report.

Would some one paste the proper code to pass same parameter to sub report.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
  cryRpt.Subreports("Your Sub Report").SetDataSource(Your Data Source)
```

to set parameter in sub report use

```
  cryRpt.SetParameterValue("Sub report Parameter", Value of the parameter, "Sub report Name")
```

Comment: How this sets the parameter in sub report? I am not using a dataset as report source.

Comment: I tried that too Mr. Abdulrahman but unfortunately it always raise an error saying: index was outside the bounds of the array! Any ideas why this is coming?

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi Are you sure that there is same name parameter inside the subreport??

Comment: Yes, I am sure dear. I think I should have the parameter name within paranthesis {@serviceNo}

Comment: Actually {?@serviceNo}

Comment: does the report object browser identify the parameter(can see it)?? if yes it must work otherwise there is a problem in defining the parameter

Answer (score 1):

First open main report->create subreport->right click on subreport. Then add report name ->goto the reportwizard-> add dataset value->if u want some filter and group feild. then write otherwise dont write any thing on there->finish.  (add 2 dataset using create subreport)
Here is my code:

```
If flag_daily_tally.Length > 0 Then
                    '   Dim mainreport As New rpt_ipd_billLogo1
                    '  Dim subreport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
                    '
                    Dim Str() As String = Nothing
                    Str = flag_daily_tally.Split("#")
                    'p15042022
                    Dim ds1 As dataset

                    ds1 = New DataSet("Ds_ipd_bill_charge")
                    ' ds = TRIO_Proc.FillDataSQLDS("SELECT * from View_OpdRegister where doa >='" & Format(Mfromdt, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' and doa<='" & Format(Mtodt, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "'")
                    ds1 = TRIO_Proc.FillDataSQLDS("SELECT IP_INVDET.BILLDT, IP_INVDET.DAYS, IP_INVDET.HRS, IP_INVDET.RATE, IP_INVDET.TOT, IP_INVMST.BILLNO, IP_INVMST.AdmTime, IP_INVMST.DOD, IP_INVMST.CNAME, IP_INVMST.DOD_TIME, IP_INVMST.P_ADDRESS, SERVICESMST.SerDisc, _WARD.NAME, IP_INVMST.DOA, IP_INVMST.PCd, IP_INVMST.IPDNO, IP_INVMST.DRNAME, IP_INVMST.INVTYPE, IP_INVDET.ip_drname, IP_INVMST.PINVNO, IP_INVDET.SRNO, IP_INVMST.BILLDT FROM   ((TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.IP_INVDET IP_INVDET INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.IP_INVMST IP_INVMST  ON IP_INVDET.BILLNO=IP_INVMST.BILLNO) INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.SERVICESMST SERVICESMST ON IP_INVDET.SERCD=SERVICESMST.SerCd)  INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo._WARD _WARD ON IP_INVDET.ROOMCODE=_WARD.SRNO where IP_INVdet.BILLNO=" & Str(0) & " and  SERVICESMST.SerDisc<>'CONSULTANT PROFESSIONAL CHARGES' ")
                    'inv_det
                    cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(0))

                    Dim ds2 As DataSet

                    '  ds2 = New DataSet("Ds_ipd_bill")
                    cryRpt.Subreports(0).SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa123123#")

                    ds2 = TRIO_Proc.FillDataSQLDS("SELECT IP_INVDET.BILLDT, IP_INVDET.DAYS, IP_INVDET.HRS, IP_INVDET.RATE, IP_INVDET.TOT, IP_INVMST.BILLNO, IP_INVMST.AdmTime, IP_INVMST.DOD, IP_INVMST.CNAME, IP_INVMST.DOD_TIME, IP_INVMST.P_ADDRESS, SERVICESMST.SerDisc, _WARD.NAME, IP_INVMST.DOA, IP_INVMST.PCd, IP_INVMST.IPDNO, IP_INVMST.DRNAME, IP_INVMST.INVTYPE, IP_INVDET.ip_drname, IP_INVMST.PINVNO, IP_INVDET.SRNO, IP_INVMST.BILLDT FROM   ((TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.IP_INVDET IP_INVDET INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.IP_INVMST IP_INVMST  ON IP_INVDET.BILLNO=IP_INVMST.BILLNO) INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo.SERVICESMST SERVICESMST ON IP_INVDET.SERCD=SERVICESMST.SerCd)  INNER JOIN TRIO_Hospitality.dbo._WARD _WARD ON IP_INVDET.ROOMCODE=_WARD.SRNO where IP_INVdet.BILLNO=" & Str(0) & " and SERVICESMST.DEPTCAT ='10001' and  SERVICESMST.SerDisc='CONSULTANT PROFESSIONAL CHARGES' ")

                    cryRpt.Subreports(0).SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa123123#")

                    cryRpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(ds2.Tables(0))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("clinic_name", dmsz_clinicname, "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("clinic_address", dmsz_clinc_address, "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    ' cryRpt.SetParameterValue("clinic_address", dmsz_clinc_address, "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("consulting_dr", Str(7), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("adv", Str(1), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("conc", Convert.ToDouble(Str(2)), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("tot_amt", Convert.ToDouble(Str(3)), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("paid_bal_amt", Convert.ToDouble(Str(4)), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("amountpay", Convert.ToDouble(Str(5)), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("company_name", Str(12), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("user_name", Str(13), "rpt_ipd_bill_2.rpt")

                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("clinic_name", dmsz_clinicname)
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("clinic_address", dmsz_clinc_address)
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("consulting_dr", Str(7))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("adv", Str(1))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("conc", Convert.ToDouble(Str(2)))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("tot_amt", Convert.ToDouble(Str(3)))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("paid_bal_amt", Convert.ToDouble(Str(4)))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("amountpay", Convert.ToDouble(Str(5)))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("company_name", Str(12))
                    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("user_name", Str(13))
```